# Explicitly marking derived class as implementing interface of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

```
interface IBase
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Base : IBase
{
    public Base() => this.Name = "Base";
    public string Name { get; }
}

class Derived : Base//, IBase
{
    public Derived() => this.Name = "Derived";
    public new string Name { get; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase o = new Derived();
        Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
    }
}
```

In this case output will be "Base".

If I explicitly state that Derived implements IBase (which is in fact already implemented by base class Base and such annotation seem to be useless) the output will be "Derived"

```
class Derived : Base, IBase
{
    public Derived() => this.Name = "Derived";
    public new string Name { get; }
}
```

What's the reason for such behavior?

VS 15.3.5, C# 7

Comment: Why should it behave otherwise?  What is your expectation?

Comment: Expectations - same output, same members accessed. I don't see why adding interface to class definition when such interface already implemented by base class can change things.

Comment: Do you understand what `public new string Name { get; }` is doing to `Name` on `Base`?

Comment: Nested class initialisation matters

Comment: In `IBase o = new Derived();` the compiler has 2 choices, it picks the best match.

Comment: This is a well-thought and legitimate question. The second specification of derivation from `IBase` might not seem to add "more information" at first glance, indeed!

Comment: Good question, I was searching for how to access derived members when base's interface is used to declare ``IBase o = new Derived();``

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's explained in sections 13.4.4 to 13.4.6 of the C# 5 specification. The relevant sections are quoted below, but basically if you explicitly state that a class implements an interface, that triggers interface mapping again, so the compiler takes *that* class as the one to use to work out which implementation each interface member is mapped to.

> **13.4.4 Interface mapping**
>
> A class or struct must provide implementations of all members of the interfaces that are listed in the base class list of the class or struct. The process of locating implementations of interface members in an implementing class or struct is known as interface mapping.
>
> Interface mapping for a class or struct `C` locates an implementation for each member of each interface specified in the base class list of `C`. The implementation of a particular interface member `I.M`, where `I` is the interface in which the member `M` is declared, is determined by examining each class or struct `S`, starting with `C` and repeating for each successive base class of `C`, until a match is located:
>
> - If `S` contains a declaration of an explicit interface member implementation that matches `I` and `M`, then this member is the implementation of `I.M`.
> - Otherwise, if `S` contains a declaration of a non-static public member that matches M, then this member is the implementation of `I.M`. If more than one member matches, it is unspecified which member is the implementation of `I.M`. This situation can only occur if `S` is a constructed type where the two members as declared in the generic type have different signatures, but the type arguments make their signatures identical.
>
> ...
>
> **13.4.5 Interface implementation inheritance**
>
> A class inherits all interface implementations provided by its base classes.
>   Without explicitly re-implementing an interface, a derived class cannot in any way alter the interface mappings it inherits from its base classes. For example, in the declarations
>
> ```
> interface IControl
> {
>     void Paint();
> }
> class Control: IControl
> {
>     public void Paint() {...}
> }
> class TextBox: Control
> {
>     new public void Paint() {...}
> }
> ```
>
> the `Paint` method in `TextBox` hides the `Paint` method in `Control`, **but it does not alter the mapping of `Control.Paint` onto `IControl.Paint`**, and calls to `Paint` through class instances and interface instances will have the following effects
>
> ```
> Control c = new Control();
> TextBox t = new TextBox();
> IControl ic = c;
> IControl it = t;
> c.Paint();            // invokes Control.Paint();
> t.Paint();            // invokes TextBox.Paint();
> ic.Paint();           // invokes Control.Paint();
> it.Paint();           // invokes Control.Paint();
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **13.4.6 Interface reimplementation**
>
> A class that inherits an interface implementation is permitted to re-implement the interface by including it in the base class list.
>
> A re-implementation of an interface follows exactly the same interface mapping rules as an initial implementation of an interface. Thus, the inherited interface mapping has no effect whatsoever on the interface mapping established for the re-implementation of the interface. For example, in the declarations
>
> ```
> interface IControl
> {
>     void Paint();
> }
> class Control: IControl
> {
>     void IControl.Paint() {...}
> }
> class MyControl: Control, IControl
> {
>     public void Paint() {}
> }
> ```
>
> the fact that `Control` maps `IControl.Paint` onto `Control.IControl.Paint` doesn’t affect the re-implementation in `MyControl`, which maps `IControl.Paint` onto `MyControl.Paint`.

Comment: Your introduction is more explanatory than the citations. But a question, when you say `that triggers interface mapping again`, what does `again` mean? In what order is the interfacing done, not from child to parent(s), like the order of constructors being fired? Meaning the first interface mapping just 'wins' ?

Comment: Thanks for such expanded answer. Confusing point was that it is possible to re-implement interface without implementing interface explicitly (syntaxwise) in any of two classes (Base, Derived), just by mixin in interface to class definition.

Comment: @nl-x: I mean that interface mapping is performed when compiling `Base`, and then again when compiling `Derived`. The is a compile-time choice, so it doesn't have an execution-time order... I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: I shouldn't have referred to (runtime) execution order of constructors, that is confusing. But if I understood correctly, the interface member is mapped to both the parent's member and child class's member. Is the mapping overwritten, or do both mapping exist, and the child mapping 'wins' when called?

Comment: @nl-x: It's not mapped to both at the same time - the mapping is done again from scratch for `Derived` because it explicitly says that it implements the interface. You can think of each class having a complete mapping for all interfaces it implements including inherited ones; if the class doesn't declare that it implements an interface, the mapping is inherited from the base class.

Answer (score 1):

If `Derived` does not implement `IBase` and declares `new string Name`, that means that `Derived.Name` and `IBase.Name` are logically not the same. So when you access `IBase.Name`, it looks for it in `Base` class, implementing `IBase`. If you remove `new string Name` property, the output will be `Derived`, because now `Derived.Name` = `Base.Name` = `IBase.Name`. If you implement `IBase` excplicitly, the output will be `Derived`, because now `Derived.Name` = `IBase.Name`. If you cast `o` to `Derived`, the output will be `Derived`, because now you are accessing `Derived.Name` instead of `IBase.Name`.