# Why IDictionary<TKey, TValue> implements both ICollection and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

I was looking at the metadata generated for `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface and I noticed it implements

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable
```

Isn't this redundant? Looking at the metadata of `ICollection<T>` it shows that it already implements `IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable`

And why does `IEnumerable<T>` implments `IEnumerable`, while `ICollection<T>` doesn't implement `ICollection`?

Comment: Have you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541462/explicitly-marking-derived-class-as-implementing-interface-of-base-class?

Comment: Metadata lists all implemented interfaces, whether directly or indirectly. Second question has answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2353346/5311735

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metadata show all implemented interfaces, especially those obtained through inheritance. If you look into the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/idictionary.cs) of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you see that the actual implementation only implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`:

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Comment: So it is just showing all the interfaces it is implementing (recursively), not just the ones that are declared explicity

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces/). It explains everything you want to know about your first question.

I quote the most relevant part:

> **Why do tools like Reflector or the object browser show the whole list?**
>
> Those tools do not have the source code. They only have metadata to
>   work from. Since putting in the full list is optional, the tool has no
>   idea whether the original source code contains the full list or not.
>   It is better to err on the side of more information. Again, the tool
>   is attempting to help you by *showing you more information* rather than
>   *hiding information you might need*.