# Different list of ancestor C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Can anyone explain me please, why the definition of a class contains some ancestors

```
public class SynchronizedCollection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection
```

but in its sources I see only

```
public class SynchronizedCollection<T> : IList<T>, IList
```

Comment: What are the ancestors of `IList<T>` and `IList`, I wonder?

Comment: `public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable`

Comment: `public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable`

Comment: Interfaces are not ancestors of a class. Every class has its own list of interfaces it implements. If an interface inherits from another interface, the class will necessarily end up implementing all inherited interfaces as well, whether it explicitly says so or not. This is in contrast to actual class inheritance, where there's only the immediate ancestor.

Comment: Answers to this are likely to be opinions, since we are wondering why Microsoft chose to add the explicit documentation for the base classes to the online documentation, but: In my *opinion* it's so that you don't have to go off and look up what `IList<T>` and `IList` implement.

Comment: Then again, mentioning interfaces in a class definition that are already implemented by directly implemented interfaces [has a purpose too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541581/11683).

Comment: From an IL perspective, the metadata of the class includes the list of all interfaces it implements. In other words, if you generate documentation or lookup information from there, you'll get a complete list of interfaces regardless of what the source said. You could reduce the list based on what interfaces inherit from each other and how the class maps them, but this is additional work.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) is the online documentation, and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.servicemodel/system/servicemodel/SynchronizedCollection.cs) is the actual implementation.

Comment: Will someome post the answer?